# Parent process spawns multiple child. How are stdio streams "shared?"

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I am confused with the following statement in Node.js documentation on child process:

**The 'close' event is emitted when the stdio streams of a child process have been closed. This is distinct from the 'exit' event, *since multiple processes might share the same stdio streams*.**

What multiple processes is this referring to? A parent can spawn multiple child processes. But each stdout of the child process is received as a separate stream by the parent, as in:

```
  spawnedProcess1.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
          });
  spawnedProcess2.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
          });
```

Similarly, each spawned process can be written to separately through its stdin, as in:

```
   spawnedProcess1.stdin.write(objToChild);
   spawnedProcess2.stdin.write(objToChild);
```

In this context, can someone explain  "*since multiple processes might share the same stdio streams.*"

Comment: Found any explanation? please share :)